# How to install Dotnet 45 on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, dotnet

Im trying to install dotnet 45 for run application in wine by this manual (https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25478), there is some problem:

After this command: winetricks dotnet45 corefonts

I get the Dotnet 2.0 installation window which is closing up with error " cant be installed on 64 bit system"

I tried to install dotnet 20 separately but it doesnt helped me, tried to use WINEARCH both 32 and 64 bit mode, but both ways does not helped me too. First one says it cant be run, second one same issue with 20 dotnet

Comment: Perhaps do you need `wine-mono` package instead?

Answer (score 4):

Do this. It configures a new wine 32bit prefix and installs it.

```
env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet45
```

Comment: but ive had some problems with it